# how to install gapps on xperia ray with previously installed cyanogenmod 10

Tags: sony-ericsson-xperia-ray

I have installed cm 10 on xperia ray, but unfortunately forgot to install Google apps. Can anyone explain how can i install Google apps now?
Thanks

Comment: Use [goo.im](http://goo.im/gapps) to select the appropriate GApps for your CM10 and install it via CWM. *Just noticed the answer below, highlight the linky by mouse hovering and it will* **take** you there.... ahem :P

Answer (score 1):

You can install Google Apps any time you want. You can download a gapps package from [here](http://goo.im/gapps) (pick the one corresponding to your CyanogenMod version). Then flash it like you did for CM10 (no need to wipe anything).

Comment: *just download a gapps package **from here***? How?

Comment: _From here_ ->  _from a forum like XDA_

Comment: Maybe "there" is better...

Comment: maybe... Maybe **here** with a specific link would be even better :)

Comment: Yepp. And make sure to pick the right ones, as they depend on the Android version used.